# Declaring a variable of an abstract class type

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have an abstract baseclass with some protected members, but no abstract members:

```
internal abstract class BaseClass
{

    protected readonly string Var1;
    protected readonly string Var2;

    protected BaseClass(string var1, string var2)
    {
        Var1 = var1;
        Var2 = var2;
    }

    protected int DoSomething1(string s)
    {
    }
}
```

And some classes that implements this baseclass and have some specific methods different for each one:

```
internal sealed class Child1:BaseClass
{
    internal Child1(string var1, string var2)
        : base(var1, var2)
    {
    }

    internal bool DomeSomethingSpecificForChild1(int i)
    {
    }

}
```

Now I have another class where I would like to have a variable of type `BaseClass` and depending of what I need, intantiate it with a child type.
But this isn't working since the specific methods are not known.

```
public class MyClass
{
        private BaseClass myBaseClass;

    public bool DomeSomethingSpecific(int i)
    {
            myBaseClass = new Child1("a","b");
            myBaseClass.DomeSomethingSpecificForChild1(i);
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can accomplish what I want?
Or do I have to declare my variable in the inner scope of my method in `MyClass`?

```
public class MyClass
{
        private BaseClass myBaseClass;

    public bool DomeSomethingSpecific(int i)
    {
            var child1 = new Child1("a","b");
            myBaseClass.DomeSomethingSpecificForChild1(i);
    }
}
```

but this way I have no certainty that the class implements `BaseClass`.

An interface is not an option since I want it to stay internal, not public,
and I don't want the baseclass to be instantiated, so I thought that abstract would be a good choice here..

Comment: Your code wont work as is, You have to mark the function virtual which you want to override in child class, also you need to use "override" keyword while defining function in child class

Comment: @MSUH I know, but the thing is that I don't want to override any method. I've put the memthods which are the same for each class as protected method in the baseclass. In the childclass I can put anything I like. I just would like to ensure that the classes I instantiate in "MyClass" do implement the "BaseClass".

Comment: Then you need to check 
if (child1 is BaseClass){child1.DomeSomethingSpecificForChild1(1);}

Comment: I'm afraid you're right. Maybe I have to look for a different setup, because this is not exactly what I was looking for... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private BaseClass child;

public bool DomeSomethingSpecific(int i)
{
        var c = {initialization to an instance - e.g. Child1(), Child2(), Child3()..};
        if (c is Child1){
            ((Child1)c).DomeSomethingSpecificForChild1(i);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use an abstract method:

```
internal abstract class BaseClass
{

    protected readonly string Var1;
    protected readonly string Var2;

    protected BaseClass(string var1, string var2)
    {
        Var1 = var1;
        Var2 = var2;
    }

    protected int DoSomething1(string s)
    {
    }

    public abstract bool DoSomethingSpecific(int i);
}
```

And then

```
internal sealed class Child1:BaseClass
{
    internal Child1(string var1, string var2)
        : base(var1, var2)
    {
    }

    public override bool DomeSomethingSpecific(int i)
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Thought of this one too, but the names and the number of methods are different for each child, so making them abstract was not an option.

Comment: @Koen It is not a good idea because if you make the name different for each, you will need a bunch of `if` to try casting into all those types to decide what to call. Why is the name that important?

Comment: Because it has a different functionality. The members that are the same, are the protected members in the baseclass. The rest in the childclass can be anything. I just wanted some structure in "MyClass" that would enforce that the classes I use there should implement BaseClass.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the child class object to base class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool DomeSomethingSpecific(int i)
    {
            var child1 = new Child1("a","b");
            ((myBaseClass)child1).DomeSomethingSpecificForChild1(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously declaring you variable as a base-class instance you can use only methods exposed by the base-class.

To use specific class methods you need to cast you object, so:

```
if(child is Child1)
{
    Child1 c1 = child as Child1
    if(c1 != null) c1.specificMethod1();
}
if(child is Child2)
{
    Child2 c2 = child as Child2
    if(c2 != null) c2.specificMethod2();
}
// ...
```